# How can I trigger a Monit event when a service comes back up?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, monitoring, monit

Given a config like this:

```
check host web1 address web1
    if failed host web1 port 80 protocol http
    then exec "/usr/local/bin/failover.sh -h web2"
```

Can I detect if web1 has returned from failed state, and perform a "fail back" action?

If I were just to detect if it was up, then I would be running the failover command every daemon seconds, and I don't want to do that if I don't have to; it would provide needless log entries and alerts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Eric Pailleau for [his suggestion](http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/monit-general/2010-08/msg00002.html) which lead to a working answer:

```
check host web1 address web1
    if failed host web1 port 80 protocol http
        then exec "/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/test ! -f /var/tmp/web-failover && ( /usr/local/bin/failover.sh -h web2 ; touch /var/tmp/auth-failover )'"
    else if succeeded
        then exec "/bin/sh -c '/usr/local/bin/failover.sh -h web1 ; rm -f /var/tmp/web-failover)'"
```

It's odd, but if you call /bin/bash on succeeded, monit doesn't seem to run the command.  I suspect it thinks it has run the command already, so doesn't bother.  It doesn't seem to mind running the first command over and over however!